# Create record using React form component

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, activerecord, reactjs

React Component

```
var ExamForm = React.createClass({
  handleSubmit: function ( event ) {
    var course_name = this.refs.courseName.getDOMNode().value;
    $.ajax({
      url: "/administration/exams",
      type: "POST",
      data: {
        exam: { class_name: course_name }
      }
    });
    this.refs.form.getDOMNode().reset();
    return false;
  },
  render: function () {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={ this.handleSubmit } className="form-horizontal" ref="form">
            <input type="text" className="form-control" ref="courseName"/>
            <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary pull-right">Create</button>
      </form>
    )
  }
});
```

Controller

```
require_dependency "administration/application_controller"

module Administration
  class ExamsController < ApplicationController
    def create
      @exam = Exam.new(exam_params)
      if @exam.save
        #Go to index page
      else
        #Display basic error message
      end
    end
    private
    def exam_params
      params.require(:exam).permit(:class_name)
    end
  end
end
```

I want to create a new Exam record from a form that is filled out in a React component. So far all I have been getting is "POST localhost:3001/administration/exams 500 (Internal Server Error)". I don't know how to debug this error. I will also accept any answer that achieves what I am trying to do, namely Ajax Post data from a React Component.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `return false` with `event.preventDefault()`.